# Error in simple SAS macro

Tags: macros, sas

I am testing the macro loop. The code is simple but always come the error message "Macro function %SCAN has too many arguments". Could not understand the reason. Anyone could explain it? Thanks!
The code is:

```
%macro test;
 proc sql;select distinct tj, max(tj) into: tp separated by ",", : maxtp from ASA_k where tj>0;quit;    

 %do i=1 %to &maxtp.;
  %let timep=%scan(&tp.,&i.,",");
  %put &timep.;
 %end;

%mend;

%test;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In macro-varriable, you store values separated by commas, these commas are problematic. You need to mask them after resolving a macro-variable, using `%bquote` macro-function. Also your third parameter in `%scan` function is not right, because your separator are `,` and `"`. You have to just mask comma using `%str` macro-function. Just like that:

```
%macro test;
 proc sql;
     select distinct tj, max(tj) 
     into :tp separated by ",", :maxtp 
     from ASA_k 
     where tj>0;
 quit;    

 %do i=1 %to &maxtp.;
  %let timep=%scan(%bquote(&tp.),&i.,%str(,));
  %put &timep.;
 %end;
%mend;

%test;
```

Comment: Or just use separated by another character

Comment: Thanks for explanation, Robert!